# How to remove orphaned controls using Designer?

Tags: .net, winforms, visual-studio, designer

I deleted `DataGridView1` placed inside a form and some time later I found that its former columns, e.g. `DataGridViewTextBoxColumn1` ～ `DataGridViewTextBoxColumn5` are still present in dropdown list on top of *Properties* tool window.

However, they are not present in *Document Outline* tool window, because they are orphans now.

Is there some way to remove them using the designer instead of messing with auto-generated code behind the form?

Comment: That's not normal.  Can't duplicate that problem.  You may have to carefully delete the line items in the designer file (make a backup first).

Comment: @LarsTech – I agree this could be due to some problem/bug in the IDE, because this specific designer file was never edited manually before (what could theoretically cause the problem otherwise). Also, this is not the first time I have met exactly this problem with orphaned DataGridView columns after deleting their parent DataGridView.